# How to convert a string into bignum in C code which extends Guile?

Tags: c, guile

In Guile 1.6.*, the function `scm_istring2number(char *str,int strlen,int radix)` does the work.

However, this function does not exist in Guile 1.8.*.
How can I accomplish the same task in Guile 1.8.*?

This is not trivial because the function `scm_string_to_number(SCM str,int radix)` does not convert numbers larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (at least in Guile 1.6.*).

Comment: Should be tagged lisp and scheme, too.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It's Guile-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the 1.8 ChangeLog, the function has been renamed `scm_c_locale_stringn_to_number`.

Comment: In 1.8, scm_string_to_number actually unpacks the SCM values and passes them to scm_c_locale_stringn_to_number, so it should handle bignums too.

Comment: I found out that scm_string_to_number expects also the radix argument as SCM, and once I fixed it, it worked also for bignums.